# Weird Spring Boot initialization queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

So i started to log all queries of my spring boot application via a proxy data source and came across some queries i couldn't explain to myself.

This is the json log of said queries:

```json
[  
  {
    "name": "TOXI",
    "connection": 3,
    "isolation": "READ_COMMITTED",
    "time": 2,
    "success": true,
    "type": "Prepared",
    "batch": false,
    "querySize": 1,
    "batchSize": 0,
    "query": [
      "select * from information_schema.sequences"
    ],
    "params": [
      []
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "TOXI",
    "connection": 3,
    "isolation": "READ_COMMITTED",
    "time": 2,
    "success": true,
    "type": "Prepared",
    "batch": false,
    "querySize": 1,
    "batchSize": 0,
    "query": [
      "select * from \"public\".\"toxi_image\" where 1=0"
    ],
    "params": [
      []
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "TOXI",
    "connection": 3,
    "isolation": "READ_COMMITTED",
    "time": 0,
    "success": true,
    "type": "Prepared",
    "batch": false,
    "querySize": 1,
    "batchSize": 0,
    "query": [
      "select * from \"public\".\"toxi_tag\" where 1=0"
    ],
    "params": [
      []
    ]
  },
]
```

The first one still makes sense to me, but the second and third one is where my question start.
Why are they needed? Shouldn't the information schema hold all the table information thats needed? And why is making this statement only for 2 tables and not for the rest of the application?

One last thing to mention, the two tables/entities have a many to many correlation, if that has something to do with it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe this is because of the relation. Once you have eager loading the related entities will automatically fetch.. https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading#:~:text=Eager%20Loading%20is%20a%20design,as%20long%20as%20it's%20possible.

Comment: The relationship isn't set to eager and the query wouldn#t return anything anyway